# Passing bitmap from C# to C++ via a struct

Tags: c#, c++, image, opencv, ffi

First, I've read the a few questions regarding this issue, the most helpful being:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463876/passing-bitmap-from-c-sharp-to-c

I was unable to get the provided solutions to work as I kept getting an `AccessViolationException`.

What I'm attempting to do is pass bitmap data to an unmanaged c++ dll. To do this I created a struct which holds a pointer to the image data as well as its length. I'm using a struct as I plan on passing in multiple images (in a single call) to the unmanaged API.

What I implemented **works** but I have a feeling there is probably some serious drawbacks so I'm curious as to what those drawbacks could be.

My current solution uses a generic pointer to hold the image data. This of course would be a drawback as I lose type safety. Anyway here is the relevant code.

---

## C++ dll

**raw_image.h**

```
struct raw_image
{
   void* data;
   int size;
};
```

**alignment.cpp (exports)**

```
ALIGNMENT_API void submit( raw_image& img )
{
    cv::Mat mat = cv::imdecode( cv::_InputArray(
        static_cast<uchar*>( img.data ), img.size ), cv::IMREAD_COLOR );
    cv::imshow( "image", mat );
    cv::waitKey( );
    cv::destroyWindow( "image" );
}
```

---

## C# dll

**RawImage.cs**

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
internal unsafe struct RawImage
{
    internal void* ImageData;
    internal int Size;
}
```

**Aligner.cs (import)**

```
[DllImport( "alignment-vc141-mtd-x64.dll", CallingConvention = 
 CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
    static extern void submit( RawImage img );
```

And this is where I pass the image to the unmanaged API.

```
using( var bitmap = new Bitmap( "AlignmentCenter.jpg" ) )
using( var stream = new MemoryStream( ) )
{
    bitmap.Save( stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
    var source = stream.ToArray( );
    fixed( void* ptr = source )
    {
        var raw = new RawImage
        {
            ImageData = ptr,
            Size = source.Length
        };
        submit( raw );
     }
  }
```

Is what I'm doing unsafe? Am I copying more than I should? 
One last thing, I know about `EmguCv` and I've used it in the past but I won't be using it here.

Comment: You could create a `c++/cli` wrapper for the native API and let it do the hard lifting with pointers and calling the native function so that you can keep your C# code _clean_.

Comment: @t3chb0t I originally planned on using `C++/CLI` for this, but ended up just using `pinvoke` for its simplicity. I'm not very familiar with `C++/CLI`. That being said, at the end of the day, if `C++/CLI` is the better option than I'll write a wrapper around the unmanaged `dll`.

Comment: When not using system functions I find such a wrapper easier to use than `pinvoke` because with it you can use `C#` more _naturally_ without the native stuff and you can work with the native stuff without workarounds inside the `C++/CLI` wrapper because it can more _naturally_ communicate with native code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Am I copying more than I should?"?

Comment: @HenrikHansen Currently I'm copying the contents of the `Bitmap` in to the `MemoryStream`. I was curious if this was necessary, or if I should use the `Bitmap`'s `scan0` property, and locking the `Bitmap`'s pixels and then passing an `IntPtr` to the unmanaged API..

Comment: @WBuck: but that - I think - depends on, what you are going to use the information for on the C++ side. Don't you need information about the image type, size, resolution etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to review. The only thing I can contribute with is that you don't have to run in `unsafe` mode:

If you define the data structure as:

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  internal struct RawImage
  {
    internal IntPtr ImageData;
    internal int Size;
  }
```

Then you can run the .NET side as:

```
  using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"fileName.Jpeg"))
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    var source = stream.ToArray();

    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
      handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(source.Length);
      Marshal.Copy(source, 0, handle, source.Length);

      var raw = new RawImage
      {
        ImageData = handle,
        Size = source.Length
      };
      submit(raw);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
      }
    }
  }
```

The above works with the same signature for `submit(RawImage img)`.

It's a little more code, but you are not limiting the use of your module.

Comment: Yeah I prefer this solution, more `C#` friendly.

Comment: will this also work for c++/cli ?

Answer (score 3):

Both your and Henrik's approach can be optimized by replacing `stream.ToArray()` with [`stream.GetBuffer()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=netframework-4.7.2). This returns the `MemoryStream`'s internal buffer array instead of making a copy.

You do have to take into account that the buffer can be larger than the actual data, so use the `Length` of the stream, not of the buffer. It's also possible that the data doesn't start at index 0, but that's only the case if you used one of the `MemoryStream` constructors that accepts an array, index and count. No problem here, but something to keep in mind if you want to generalize this.